# My CSS isn't applying to my PHP include files properly

Tags: php, html, css

I made a post recently about an issue, but I linked my code with pictures instead of adding it properly and I wasn't clear about my problem, so people marked it as a duplicate to another question here at stackoverflow, but that question wasn't about the same issue I had exactly so I making a new PROPER post here to try get some help with my issue.

I have built a framwork with pages and php include files. 
But my CSS file isn't applying the changes to the files properly and I cant seem to find the issue.

Below shows how my files are sorted:

```
Root Directory   
 - CSS (folder)
 - Includes (folder)
 - All the main pages
```

[My folders if the explanation above wasnt clear enough (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqWsd.png)

In this project the basic code that is on the frontpage is split up in different include files to be able to change things in the include file and apply it everywhere, like the menu.

Code of my Main Page:
(there you can see the include to the `header.php` and in the bottom the includes to the footer and sidebar)

```
 <?php
$page_title = "Startsida";
include("includes/header.php");
?>
<div class="pagecontent"> <!-- sidornas huvudinnehåll -->
<h2>Startsidan</h2>
<h2>Frågor och Svar:</h2>

<h3>Har du tidigare erfarenhet av utveckling med PHP?</h3>
        <p>
            Jag har innan denna kurs inte använt PHP i praktiken utan har genom intresse gjort en mindre del via CodeAcademy. Jag tyckte det var intressant men under denna period kunde jag inget annan språk och då var det ju svårt att faktiskt göra något med den lilla PHP kunskapen jag hade. <br> Det vi gått igenom för denna uppgift är redan mer än vad jag kunde om PHP innan. 
        </p>

<h3>Beskriv kortfattat vad du upplever är fördelarna med att använda PHP för att skapa webbplatser.</h3> 
        <p>
            Jag känner direkt bara genom det man hittils har gjort genom att sätta upp sitt ramverk med hemsidan att det är så mycket mer effektivt. Då jag skulle lägga till alla undersidor till exempel var en enkel ändring på min "mainmenu.php" fil för att ge alla sidor den nya menyn. 
        </p>    

<h3>Hur har du valt att strukturera upp dina filer och kataloger?</h3> 
        <p>
          Jag har strukturerat upp mina filer med index filern och undersidorna i en katalog och sedan de mindre controll filerna såsom header,mainmenu och footer etc har jag lagt i en separat mapp som jag valde att döpa till includes.   
        </p> 

<h3>Har du följt guiden, eller skapat på egen hand?</h3> 
        <p>
           Jag har följt guiden för denna uppgift men kommer nog göra ändringar efter min peronliga smak när jag känner mig säker att göra detta.  
        </p>   

<h3>Har du gjort några förbättringar eller vidareutvecklingar av guiden (om du följt denna)?</h3> 
        <p>
            hittils har jag ej gjort några ändringar i min uppbyggad av webbplatsen från var guiden har visat. 
        </p>  

<h3>Vilken utvecklingsmiljö har du använt för uppgiften (Editor, webbserver (XAMPP, LAMP, MAMP eller liknande) etcetera)?</h3> 
        <p>
            Jag har använt Sublime Text som editor, XAMPP för databas och server.
        </p>  

<h3>Har något varit svårt med denna uppgift?</h3> 
        <p>
            Vid skrivande stund så har jag inte stött på något jag inte kunnat lösa eller som varit för svårt. 
        </p>    

</div>
<?php
include("includes/sidebar.php");
include("includes/footer.php");
```

Code in the header.php:
(Here you can see the include to the mainmenu.php aswell)

```
<?php include("includes/config.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <title><?= $site_title . $divider . $page_title; ?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stilmall.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header id="mainheader">
            <h1>PHP Struktur</h1>


               <?php include("includes/mainmenu.php") ?>




        </header>
        </div>
```

And here is the code for the mainmenu.php

```
<nav id="mainmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Hem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida1.php">Undersida 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida2.php">Undersida 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida3.php">Undersida 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida4.php">Undersida 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida5.php">Undersida 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida6.php">Undersida 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

So basically the other includes is in the same way where the relevant code like the mainmenu.php is added.

So with this code,everything works properly. My includes works and is linked properly, when i change code in any include it get changed everywhere where that include file appears in the code on any page like it should.

BUT why isnt my css being properly applied?

As I can see it my link to the css document in the header, which either contains all the includes or is inlcuded to where the other inlcudes appears, (example the mainmenu.php is inlcluded in the header, and the header is includes in the mainpage where incliudes like sidebar and footer.php is included.

So that means that my css code should affect the header.php as it is being linked there, and it should affect all the other includes in the header.php?

Why isnt my css code being applied? I cant for the love of god see where the error is.

Source code from the mainpage requested by the comments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <title>Min webbplats | Startsida</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stilmall.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header id="mainheader">
            <h1>PHP Struktur</h1>


               <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilmall.css" type="text/css">

<nav id="mainmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Hem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida1.php">Undersida 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida2.php">Undersida 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida3.php">Undersida 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida4.php">Undersida 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida5.php">Undersida 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="undersida6.php">Undersida 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>



        </header>
        </div>

<div class="pagecontent"> <!-- sidornas huvudinnehåll -->
<h2>Startsidan</h2>
<h2>Frågor och Svar:</h2>

<h3>Har du tidigare erfarenhet av utveckling med PHP?</h3>
        <p>
            Jag har innan denna kurs inte använt PHP i praktiken utan har genom intresse gjort en mindre del via CodeAcademy. Jag tyckte det var intressant men under denna period kunde jag inget annan språk och då var det ju svårt att faktiskt göra något med den lilla PHP kunskapen jag hade. <br> Det vi gått igenom för denna uppgift är redan mer än vad jag kunde om PHP innan. 
        </p>

<h3>Beskriv kortfattat vad du upplever är fördelarna med att använda PHP för att skapa webbplatser.</h3> 
        <p>
            Jag känner direkt bara genom det man hittils har gjort genom att sätta upp sitt ramverk med hemsidan att det är så mycket mer effektivt. Då jag skulle lägga till alla undersidor till exempel var en enkel ändring på min "mainmenu.php" fil för att ge alla sidor den nya menyn. 
        </p>    

<h3>Hur har du valt att strukturera upp dina filer och kataloger?</h3> 
        <p>
          Jag har strukturerat upp mina filer med index filern och undersidorna i en katalog och sedan de mindre controll filerna såsom header,mainmenu och footer etc har jag lagt i en separat mapp som jag valde att döpa till includes.   
        </p> 

<h3>Har du följt guiden, eller skapat på egen hand?</h3> 
        <p>
           Jag har följt guiden för denna uppgift men kommer nog göra ändringar efter min peronliga smak när jag känner mig säker att göra detta.  
        </p>   

<h3>Har du gjort några förbättringar eller vidareutvecklingar av guiden (om du följt denna)?</h3> 
        <p>
            hittils har jag ej gjort några ändringar i min uppbyggad av webbplatsen från var guiden har visat. 
        </p>  

<h3>Vilken utvecklingsmiljö har du använt för uppgiften (Editor, webbserver (XAMPP, LAMP, MAMP eller liknande) etcetera)?</h3> 
        <p>
            Jag har använt Sublime Text som editor, XAMPP för databas och server.
        </p>  

<h3>Har något varit svårt med denna uppgift?</h3> 
        <p>
            Vid skrivande stund så har jag inte stött på något jag inte kunnat lösa eller som varit för svårt. 
        </p>    

</div>
<div id="sidebar">
            <h2>Höger kolumn</h2>
            <p>Här är en "sidebar", som är lika för alla undersidor.</p>

        </div><footer id="mainfooter">
            <p>Här är webbplatsens sidfot. Samma för alla undersidor.</p>
        </footer><!-- /mainfooter -->
```

[I saw this error in the browser now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jufw3.png)

Comment: Can you post the source generated for a specific page where your CSS is not working properly?

Comment: You mean post the source code when i open it in the browser? Basically I cant get my css to apply anywhere at all

Comment: Right, seeing the source code delivered to your browser may help isolate the issue.

Comment: @AnthonyL Source code added bottom of the post

Comment: if your header.php is in the includes folder, your css path is wrong. It should be relative to your index.php, not your include.

Comment: @Ronnie So as the folder it links to, which is in the root directory it should rather than "../css....." it should be "css/....."?

Comment: you can try a relative path like "css/stilmall.css" or an absolute if you're in docroot, like "/css/stilmall.css". Have you checked your console? Are you getting a 404 on the css file?

Comment: Developer Tools in your browser would help you out greatly here. Sounds like what Ronnie mentioned, simply having the wrong location reference.

Comment: I changed it to "css/my css file name" from "../css/my css file name", that should be correct yes? Either way it still doesnt work :/

Comment: Please just open your dev tools to confirm you are not receiving an error.

Comment: @Ronnie Sorry just saw ur comment about to check for errors, and as you said you are correct and im getting an error, added the picture in the bottom of the post. Sorry for not seeing you asking for that

Comment: That error is given since you never added the question mark before `<?php echo time(); ?>`. It must be written like: `stilmall.css?<?php echo time(); ?>`

Comment: I added the question mark now, but still nothing... god dammit.. :/

Comment: Quoting myself from the reply below: "Please provide your CSS code."

Comment: @Luicy Sorry for not replying to that, I basically have an empty css file atm, I just have very basic code to see if it applies like:#mainmenu {float: left
}

Or some other small commands like removing the bullets from the menu for examply, so the css code is close to empty except for what I just sent

Comment: Tell you what.. I bet 5.000.000 kronor (swedish currency ppl) that if u add `background: #000` it will show a black background......

Comment: @Luicy It worked! Lucky I didnt take u up on that bet!

So basically what we did to fix this was:

Changed the directory as the index.php that the header links to is in the root directory and not in includes folder so it was not linking properly?

When I removed the code to check for updates in the css file constantly it went away, is that because then it no longer checks all the time and uses a cached version?

Comment: Yeep... Your CSS works just fine. :)


For clarification: `float` won't work like you intentet it to (`text-align`). Anyways, good luck on this school project or whatever it is. (Lycka till. :) )

Comment: @Luicy Yeah sorry that was a poor example, I will use text align not sure why i really used my tests with float... I think my brain was lazy in shorter to type that one :P Thanks so much for the help

Comment: All good. :) Enjoy.

Comment: @Luicy Last question real quick. Can I mark this as solved anywhere? ;P

Comment: Yeah, wait a few minutes and I'll edit my answer then hit the green button that's located here for you: http://prntscr.com/iij5au

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But my CSS file isn't applying the changes to the files properly and I cant seem to find the issue.

Sounds like a caching issue to me, recaching it can be as easy as:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stilmall.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" type="text/css">`

This reads the CSS file will be read over and over for ever millisecond ran (by time of constructing the HTML page)

Final answer.
The issue has been fixed through comments of main post:

There was an issue with both caching, file directory and CSS properties. Float was used but would not have a visual impact, instead- using `background` confirmed that everything's working fine.

Comment: Ok I see what u mean, and that should make the css being applied? That doesnt seem like the "proper" way?
Shouldnt the code just be applied as it directly links to the css folder?

Comment: it will just redownload the css file rather than use the cached version

Comment: This will help the CSS to be read over and over everytime to detect changes. Otherwise a browsers cache will not read changes in the CSS file as it reads from local files on their computers. Basically what this does, it adds a question mark which stands for a GET method action, followed with a timestamp.

Comment: As for your edit: " Shouldnt the code just be applied as it directly links to the css folder?". It's still being applied as a direct link, but it adds an invisible tag to allow changes to take place for webbrowsers that's cached the web files. Read more: https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

Comment: Ok that gives me some clarification, but i tried it and it didnt change :/

I added the php line exactly where yours where and it didnt change.

Comment: Can you clarify for me: is any of your CSS being applied at all?

Comment: @Luicy No, that is the main issue

Comment: Oh okay, that makes more sense. Will uptade answer in a sec.

Comment: @LuicyThanks! As an update: My link to the css file which was "../css/my css file" and changed it to "css/my css file" as my index file that is in the root directory is the file my header links to that contains the css link.

Comment: Ummmm.. My pal and I are abit confused of your code right now. See here: http://prntscr.com/iiix2s

Your code makes absolutely no sense to us, would you mind opening your developer tools and showing any and all HTTP error outputs? On tpo of this, please provide your CSS code.

Comment: @Luicy Sorry I manage to add the same thing twice. Im sorry if the code seems confusing.  I will remove that line of code u sent a pic of

Answer (score 1):

Although the link to the CSS file is in one of your included files, that part of the code is included in / becomes part of the main page file/s, which is/are in the root directory, therefore the CSS file is referenced *from there* (i.e from the root directory). So, instead of this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stilmall.css" type="text/css">
```

you have to put this in your `header.php`file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilmall.css" type="text/css">
```

which is the proper filepath from the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your file path is wrong, Remove `../` in the file path.

Try Using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilmall.css" type="text/css">
```